# Is it possible to Recover p12 certificate from APK?

Tags: java, android, certificate

Is it possible to recover the original p12 certificate from an APK file? I don't believe I've lost it, but the one I deem to be the correct .p12 file no longer works, throwing "IOException: Redundant length bytes found" in Flash Builder...

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. The p12 is not included in the APK.

If it were included, anyone could get it and try to break the key and could sign the application in your name

Try to check the p12 with openssl

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -in keyStore.p12
```

Or open it with [KeystoreExplorer](http://keystore-explorer.org/). if this works, export the key to another p12